# How to transform correctly shadow cascades?

Tags: rendering, directx, shadows

I think I got the main idea of shadow cascades but I have misunderstanding of transforming shadow cascades using matrices for getting correct a result. I understand it this so

1. Define shadow cascade ranges [0, 15 ],[ 10, 50 ], [ 40, 120 ], [ 100, 320 ].
2. For each a range I make a frustum box. The frustum box consist of eight vertices
   [image]
3. I transform a frustum box from camera space to world space( I get a camera matrix using XMMatrixLookAtLH )
   [image]
4. On this step I have misunderstanding. I must transform from world space to light space using light matrix in order to render a shadow map from a light perspective.
   [image]
   But i don't understand how it works. if I multiple each a frustum box to on light matrix I must get a result below because I rotate frustum boxes about a world origin not about a frustum box origin.
   [image]

```
Matrix4 make_rotation_matrix(Vector3 *direction, Vector3 *up_direction = NULL)
{
    assert(direction);

    Vector3 z_axis = normalize(direction);
    Vector3 up = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
    if (up_direction) {
        up = *up_direction;
    }
    Vector3 x_axis = normalize(&cross(&up, &z_axis));
    Vector3 y_axis = normalize(&cross(&z_axis, &x_axis));

    Matrix4 rotation_matrix = make_identity_matrix();
    rotation_matrix.set_row_0(Vector4(x_axis, 0.0f));
    rotation_matrix.set_row_1(Vector4(y_axis, 0.0f));
    rotation_matrix.set_row_2(Vector4(z_axis, 0.0f));
    return rotation_matrix;
}

void Frustum_Box::Plane::setup(float plane_width, float plane_height, float depth)
{
    plane_width *= 0.5f;
    plane_height *= 0.5f;
    origin_top_left = Vector3(-plane_width, plane_height, depth);
    origin_top_right = Vector3(plane_width, plane_height, depth);
    origin_bottom_left = Vector3(-plane_width, -plane_height, depth);
    origin_bottom_right = Vector3(plane_width, -plane_height, depth);
    
    top_left = origin_top_left;
    top_right = origin_top_right;
    bottom_left = origin_bottom_left;
    bottom_right = origin_bottom_right;
}

void Cascaded_Shadow::init(float fov, Shadow_Cascade_Range *shadow_cascade_range)
{
    range = *shadow_cascade_range;
    frustum_box.near_plane.setup((float)range.start * fov, (float)range.start * fov, (float)range.start);
    frustum_box.far_plane.setup((float)range.end * fov, (float)range.end * fov, (float)range.end);
    frustum_box.calculate_length();
    frustum_box.update_min_max_values();
}

void Cascaded_Shadow::transform(Matrix4 *transform_matrix)
{
    frustum_box.near_plane.transform_plane(transform_matrix);
    frustum_box.far_plane.transform_plane(transform_matrix);
    frustum_box.update_min_max_values();
}

bool Render_World::make_shadow(Light *light)
{
    Cascaded_Shadow_Map cascaded_shadow_map;
    
    float fov = render_sys->view.fov;
    Matrix4 light_matrix = make_view_matrix(&Vector3::zero, &light->direction);

    for (u32 i = 0; i < shadow_cascade_ranges.count; i++) {
        Cascaded_Shadow cascaded_shadow;
        cascaded_shadow.light_matrix = light_matrix;
        cascaded_shadow.init(fov, &shadow_cascade_ranges[i]);
        if (!get_shadow_atls_viewport(&cascaded_shadow.viewport)) {
            return false;
        }
        cascaded_shadow_map.cascaded_shadows.push(cascaded_shadow);
        cascaded_shadow_count++;
    }
    cascaded_shadow_maps.push(cascaded_shadow_map);
    return true;
}

void Render_World::update_shadows()
{
    for (u32 i = 0; i < cascaded_shadow_maps.count; i++) {
        for (u32 j = 0; j < cascaded_shadow_maps[i].cascaded_shadows.count; j++) {
            Cascaded_Shadow *cascaded_shadow = &cascaded_shadow_maps[i].cascaded_shadows[j];
            Matrix4 light_matrix = cascaded_shadow_maps[i].cascaded_shadows[j].light_matrix;

            cascaded_shadow->frustum_box.reset();
            cascaded_shadow->transform(&inverse(&camera.get_view_matrix()));
            cascaded_shadow->transform(&light_matrix);


            cascaded_view_projection_matrices[cascaded_shadow->view_projection_matrix_index] = cascaded_shadow->get_cascade_view_matrix() * cascaded_shadow->get_cascade_projection_matrix();
        }
    }

cascaded_view_projection_matrices_sb.update(&cascaded_view_projection_matrices);

}
```

Comment: Perhaps check out this example: https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/blob/main/CascadedShadowMaps11/CascadedShadowMaps11.cpp